# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on php json_encode

Tags: javascript

When I do this:

```
onClick = "return generateClient('<?php echo json_encode($_POST)?>');"
```

I am getting this error on the google chrome console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

But when I do this from php:

```
print_r(json_encode($_POST));
```

I get:

```
{"lang-select":"C++","question-id":"1","method-name":"Rishi","param-count":"1","lib-path":"c:\\h\\b.out","return-select":"unsigned int","sample-count":"1","class-name":"m"}
```

What can be the fault in this?

Comment: fixing syntax errors is part of the debugging process. That's something _you_ have to do yourself. This isn't a free debugger service

Comment: Have a look at the generated source or the DOM inspector. Is it how you expect it to be?

Answer (score 2):

Your data contains `"` characters.

Your attribute values are delimited by `"` characters.

The first `"` in the data will end the attribute value.

A [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would have picked this up for you.

Run your data through `htmlspecialchars` to encode the quote marks.